# Proguard and two projects using the same android library. broadcasting. ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, proguard

The problem:I have got 2 apps. The interact with each other via broadcasting. I have parcelable class in the android library (they send content of class in the library). So after using Proguard I have got ClassNotFondException. How to solve it?

```
07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver <appname>.<name>.ar.free.BRMain: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = <appname>.a.a.b)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2277)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:140)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encounteredClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = <appname>.a.a.b)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2148)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:922)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at <appname>.<name>.ar.free.BRMain.onReceive(BRMain.java:35)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2270)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     ... 10 more

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <appname>.a.a.b

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2301)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1660)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1803)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2142)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     ... 16 more

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <appname>/a/a/b

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     ... 26 more

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <appname>.a.a.b

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

07-03 02:13:51.832: E/AndroidRuntime(6801):     ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Parcelable` class needs to be added to your `proguard-project.txt` file and then proguard run again on the project.

For example, you would want to add something like the following to your `proguard-project.txt` file, substituting the fully-qualified name of *your* class of course:

```
-keep public class com.example.MyParcelableClass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You dramatically saved my time!